# Create an user in Oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, createuser

I am the first user of Oracle Database.

Now, I want to create a DB schema called ERDB.

I need to create the ERDB user and granting appropriate privileges to the ERDB user on SQL script file.

```
CREATE USER dmuser IDENTIFIED BY password 
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS 
TEMPORARY
TABLESPACE TEMP 
QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;
GRANT CREATE JOB TO dmuser; 
GRANT CREATE MINING MODEL TO dmuser; 
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO dmuser; 
GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO dmuser;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO dmuser; 
GRANT CREATE SYNONYM TO dmuser; 
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO dmuser; 
GRANT CREATE TYPE TO dmuser; 
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO dmuser; 
GRANT EXECUTE ON ctxsys.ctx_ddl TO dmuser;
```

but the error happens, SQL Error: ORA 01031 insufficient privileges;

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The [**Oracle documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF01503) clearly states the following:

> Prerequisites
>
> You must have the **CREATE USER system privilege**.

Connect as **SYSTEM**, no need of **SYSDBA** and then execute:

```
CREATE USER user IDENTIFIED BY password
```

Similarly, execute other command to create the tablespaces and required grants etc.

On a side note, regarding **SYSDBA**:

> - Never ever use SYS (or SYSDBA) but for maintenance purpose (startup, shutdown, backup, recover)
> - SYS/SYSDBA is special
> - SYS/SYSDBA is Oracle proprietary (try to open a SR/TAR starting with "i did that with SYS/SYSDBA" and you'll see the immediate answer)
> - SYS/SYSDBA does not act like any other user
> - When you use SYS/SYSDBA Oracle deactivates some code path and activates others
> - Whatever you do with SYS/SYSDBA will neither validate nor invalidate the same thing with any other user.
>
> NEVER EVER use SYS/SYSDBA for anything that can be done by another
>   user.  Use SYS/SYSDBA ONLY for something that can't be done by someone
>   else.